# What does clearing of input buffer mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, buffer

I was going through a code in my school textbook, wherein there is a line who's function is to clear the input buffer (mentioned as a comment in the code).

I couldn't quite understand its purpose. It is definitely required as its removal messes up the console input process.

Please explain what its function is, and what is happening when I remove it.

I have also tried using cin.ignore(); and it works just fine too. How is the function used here, is it an exact replacement of cin.ignore()?

P.S. In school we are using the older version of C++. Hence the ".h" extension, clrscr();, etc.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){
clrscr();

ofstream fout("student.txt", ios::out);
char name[30], ch;
float marks = 0.0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "Student " << (i+1) << ":\tName: ";
    cin.get(name,30);
    cout << "\t\tMarks: ";
    cin >> marks;
    cin.get(ch);  //for clearing input buffer (This thing!)
    fout << name << '\n' << marks << '\n';
}

fout.close();

ifstream fin("student.txt", ios::in);
fin.seekg(0);
cout << "\n";

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    fin.get(name,30);
    fin.get(ch); //Again
    fin >> marks;
    fin.get(ch); //Same
    cout << "Student Name: " << name;
    cout << "\tMarks: " << marks << "\n";
}

fin.close();
getch();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cin >> marks;
> cin.get(ch);  //for clearing input buffer (This thing!)
> ```

This is a not-so-robust way of clearing the input buffer. If you type a number followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the first line will consume the number and put the value in `marks` while the second line will read the newline character and discard it.

It is not robust since it does not account for spaces a user might have entered after the number. A more robust method would be to use [`istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

```
cin >> marks;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to start with pointing out that you are not using "the older version of C++". You are just using some c code (like clrscr()) and c styled programming, and indeed probably not cpp11 or cpp14. Also header files for C++ are often still just .h.

Now the answer to your question:

```
cin.get(ch);
```

The '\n' character gets read into ch. '\n' is one character, a newline character.

does indeed do the same thing as

```
cin.ignore();
```

It is used to clear the input buffer, which means that the empty end of line ('\n') is being deleted from the input buffer.

**Why** is this done you ask? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) is a good example of why you would do that. Hope this helped you!

Comment: No, he is running the "older" version of C++.  Most likely he is using turbo C++ which runs a pre-standard/non-standard version of C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver My bad, sorry. Thanks for pointing that out. You have to admit that "THE older version of C++" sounds pretty weird. I thought he meant "not cpp11 or cpp14".

Comment: I am a beginner when it comes to programming. Yes I use Turbo C++, I thought that it was the older version, my bad. Anyways, shouldn't cin.get(ch) be taking a character input from user and pass it to "ch"?

Comment: @PrakharAgarwal Good point, I updated my answer to clarify it for you ;)

Comment: @JulianDeclercq Okay but why is the newline character being passed into 'ch' automatically? I mean, shouldn't the console take separate inputs for 'marks' and 'ch'?